# I want to convert different type of format (str like sep 2019, int like 2018, float to datetime.datetime)

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
2010-01-01 00:00:00
Dec 2017
2008-06-01 00:00:00
2018-06-01 00:00:00
2009
2018-11-01 00:00:00
Feb 2018
2005
Aug 2017
```

i need to convert them into one format i tried this code but it contains many errors i appreciate your help

```
for i in dt[i][4] :
    if  type(i) == str:
    dt[i][4] = pd.to_datetime(dt[i][4])
```

Comment: `pd.to_datetime()` doesn't work?

Comment: Question has nothing to do with `machine-learning` - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Comment: Please show reproducible code. If you put your sample data into a Series, `pd.to_datetime` gives the expected result. Unless you show *something* allowing us to reproduce the problem, the question is *off topic* according to SO rules. As it seems to be your first question, it is probably time to read again [ask] ;-)

Comment: i don't get it i found this code when searching and it didn't work for me so i posted it here so i can find out the problem how u suggest to make it reproducible and how my question is not clear! and what do you mean by pd.to_datetime gives the expected result

Answer (score 1):

The `dateutil` module provides a [parser module](http://labix.org/python-dateutil#head-a23e8ae0a661d77b89dfb3476f85b26f0b30349c) which can detect varieties of formats and convert them to `datetime` objects.

```py
from dateutil.parser import parse
dates = [
    '2010-01-01 00:00:00',
    'Dec 2017',
    '2008-06-01 00:00:00',
    '2018-06-01 00:00:00',
    '2009',
    '2018-11-01 00:00:00',
    'Feb 2018',
    '2005',
    'Aug 2017'
]

[parse(date) for date in dates]
```

Result:

```py
[datetime.datetime(2010, 1, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 12, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2008, 6, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2009, 7, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 1, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2018, 2, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2005, 7, 10, 0, 0),
 datetime.datetime(2017, 8, 10, 0, 0)]
```

Comment: `datetime` is a standard library, IMO `pandas` is a large unnecessary dependency for simple date conversion.

Comment: I fully agree with you (and did not downvote). But the question is tagged with pandas... In addition, datetime is indeed in the standard library but dateutil is not (and is the library internally used in pandas). In any way, your answer is a honest attempt for a not so clear question :-)

Comment: Ah, sorry. You're definitely correct, got the two mixed up. At least I know `parse` exists for the future now :)